# Azure Functions in Isolated Mode - How to create a HTTP Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to set-up an Azure Isolated Function as a HTTP trigger:

```
[Function("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] 
    HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
```

However: `HttpTrigger` is in this namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
```

But when I add it, it tells me that I can't / shouldn't use that with an isolated function:

> The attribute 'HttpTriggerAttribute' is a WebJobs attribute and not
> supported in the .NET Worker (Isolated Process).

Is there an alternate process for .Net Isolated?

Following comments and answers, I've tried changing this, and have worked out that `HttpTrigger` is the real culprit. My dependencies are as follows:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Abstractions" Version="1.1.0" />    
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.31" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
```

Using statements:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: Use visual studio to create an new azure functions project and select isolated project while doing so. Then compare the package references in the .csproj with your project file. Ideally you should use `HttpRequestData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` is supported in Azure Functions Isolated Process also.**

**First, You need to install the above package from the NuGet Package Manager in the Visual Studio Project.**
[image]

**Secondly, we need to write the namespace header like `using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;` in the Http Trigger Function Class and it is greyed at starting. It is enabled until you write the code related to that namespace as you can see below:**

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

Please check your function declaration in the function class as it should be `HttpRequestData` but you have `HttpRequest`.

[image]

Comment: It turned out that this was the opposite of what I needed to do... the MS.Azure.Webjobs was causing some kind of conflict.  Now resoklved - thasnks for your help

Comment: For anyone else encountering the same problem, the key to the solution was to remove WebJobs from the dependency list entirely. I will mark this as accepted, though

Comment: Yes @gzr You're correct! `webjobs` package will not come by default to the azure function during creation. We need to install and use if needed for any `webjobs` related code purpose. Otherwise not required.

Comment: I'm kind of saying the opposite - that you should not include those packages

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a different NuGet package for isolated runtime to work.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
```

Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http is added since you are using HttpTrigger

In the case of Service bus trigger it would be Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus, Like so for other triggers as well

In local.settings.json file add FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME as dotnet-isolated

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

Remove nuget reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions package

You can review the same from Microsoft doc [Isolated process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions)

Comment: I would suggest that, instead of code prints, you provided the actual code snippets, you can read this SO Meta [anwser](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8182493) for more info